# KeyboardInterrupt handling is extremely slow. Where is the problem?

Tags: paramiko, keyboardinterrupt

I'm currently trying to write a script to read a shell via paramiko and, by far, if I prompt a single command it works great.

the problem is that my actual goal is to handle a debug flow and of course I cannot use a timeout because the script should listen without time limitations.

So the other option is to let the user stop the flow with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. I added a "try, except" handler like

```
except (IOError, SystemExit):
    raise
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Crtl+C Pressed. Shutting down.")
```

and it seemed like it wasn't working: nothing happened when pressing ctrl-c. But then I realized that it was just taking forever: after a few minutes the script actually stops and the message appears.

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

just for the reference here's my code

```
import paramiko
import time
import re
import socket
import os

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

address = '192.168.1.1'
username = 'admin' 
password = ''

ssh.connect(address, port=22, username = username, password = password)

shell = ssh.invoke_shell(height=400)
shell.settimeout(2)

def prompt_console(command = '', channel = shell, timeout = False):
    print(channel.recv(9999).decode('utf-8'))           #<-- this is for removing the initial prompt from buffer
    if timeout == False:
        shell.settimeout(3600)                          #<--increasing the timeout
    channel.send(command+'\n')
    log = ''
    while True:
        try:
            log += channel.recv(1).decode('utf-8')      #<--every loop it loads a char into the "log" variable
            if log[-9:] == '--More-- ':
                shell.send(" ")
                log.replace('--More-- \r         \r\t\t','\r\t\t')
            if len(re.findall('.*\n',log))>0:           #<--it yields every line to python console
                yield log
                log = ''
        except (IOError, SystemExit):
            raise
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print ("Crtl+C Pressed. Shutting down.")
```

I also tried to put the try-except outside the while loop but it didn't work. I also tried many suggestions that I've found on google but they didn't work either: they all stop the script eventually but for all of them it takes 5-10 minutes.

Comment: What is *"handle a debug flow"*? Why do you use `invoke_shell` instead of `exec_command`? What are you actually trying to implement?

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: for debug flow I mean a console output of debug messages. in this case I am working on a firewall. I'm not using the exec_command method because, for some reason  with some command it does not work and apparently reading the debug flow is one of them. If you prompt the command to print the debug messages and read the stdout of exec_command it doesn't contain any message. The invoke_shell method instead let you read and interact with any message. I would be more than happy if I could use the exec_command method. any help with that is welcome too.